# Django importing a value of a Class Object to another Class in the same Model

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to DJANGO, And i got stuck with a problem in my models. I tried a lot, but couldnt find a way to get the result.

```
class Destination(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

from this above Model class I want the same value of 'name' field in the below Model class

```
class Destination_individual(models.Model):

    # name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = None)
    name = 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption5 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My first Class (Destination) is migrated to the Server, and I want the Name field value from that database(Destination) to be shown in the Name field of Destination_individual database.

Please guide me how to do that.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only conceptually possible if the name of the destination is *unique*, since otherwise the name could refer to multiple `Destination`s.

We thus can set that field to unique like:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Then we can define a [**`ForeignKey`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) that refers to the `name` field of the `Destination` by setting the [**`to_field=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), like:

```
class Destination_individual(models.Model):
    name = ForeignKey(Destination, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_indiavidual')
    caption5 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Django will create a `name_id` column in the database that stores the name of the `Destination` object. It will create a foreign key constraint, such that most databases will validated that the `name_id` is referring to a valid `name` of a `Destination` record.

That being said, it is usually better to let the `ForeignKey` refer to the primary key of a model (an `AutoField`). That way, you can make use of a `GenericForeignKey`, and it makes your models more *uniform*.

Comment: Your answer was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your first model is called as you seem to have clipped that, but lets say it's called Person.

Instead of name on the othe rmodel, you should have

```
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can then reference the name of a Destination_individual using

```
person.name
```

P.S. Your class really should be named DestinationIndividual, according to Django naming standards. Not a big deal, but still.